# Save a file in folder opened by dialog box

Tags: c#, dialog

My program has a treeview which lists files from a remote computer. What I need to do is to copy these files from remote into one of my local folders. I wish that when I right click the file in treeview, a dialog box shows up for me to choose a folder, and then I click "OK" in the dialog box, my clicked file could be saved inside that folder.

Since the path of the files in remote is unc path, I'm using

```
File.Copy(string remote_address, string local_address)
```

to copy the files. As i said before I need a dialog window to choose folders. So I've tried using a `FolderBowserDialog`, however  its `SelectedPath` property returns me only the path to the folder not including the folder's name! And I haven't found any property to return me the folder's name.

So my questions are:

1. If there's a way allowing me to use `FolderBowserDialog`, that I could get the full path of the location where I save my file?
2. If there's another method allowing me to copy or download the files from remote, like using `SaveFileDialog`. The problem is I don't know how to us it to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if(fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var localPath= Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, Path.GetFilename(remote_address));
    File.Copy(remote_address, localPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which "SavePath" property you are referring to, as FolderBrowserDialog has no such property. The property you are looking for is called `SelectedPath`.

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.ShowDialog();

string local_address = dlg.SelectedPath;
```

Comment: So what's your question? I selected "Desktop" in the dialog and dlg.SelectedPath returned "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop" where `Desktop` is the name of the directory I selected. I'm not seeing the missing directory problem you've described.

Comment: when I click a folder called "local" on desktop, the returned address is "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop" and what I want is "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\local". If you could just get the path I want by using only selectedPath, I should say that's weird.

Comment: @jcraffael That's exactly how it works for me. The SelectedPath includes "local". Are you sure you're clicking the right folder in the dialog and not its parent? You're not doing any `Path.GetDirectory()`'s in your code, right??

Comment: Well since my "local" folder lies on desktop and it has no sub folders. In the folderbrowsedialog window I can just click "local" without able to open it. I wasn't using Path.GetDirectory() so I didn't have the name "local" in the path. Now thanks to others' suggestion, I'm using it in the code and the problem is solved.

Comment: Wait.. what!? Using `Path.GetDirectory()` should return the path *without* 'local'.. I feel like there is something you're not telling us, but if you solved your problem I guess that's all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

After you call the FolderBrowserDialog's ShowDialog() method it will return a variable indicating what button the user pressed (ie, Ok or Cancel)

after you make sure the user had used "Ok" to indicate they want to proceed with the operation, you can access the "SelectedPath" field which will give you the full local path they selected.

You can then get the final path by calling

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath,remoteFileName);
```

I'm assuming that fbd is your FolderBrowserDialog instance and remoteFileName should contain just the filename part of the remote file (eg. "MyFile.txt");

If you want to separate the filename from the full remote path, use

```
var remoteFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(remotePath);
```

That being said, what a user would typically expect is not a folder browser dialog, but the save file dialog.

you can initialize the save file dialog with a filename, leaving the user to select a folder and possibly change the intended file name as well if they wish.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.FileName = remoteFileName;
sfd.ShowDialog();
sfd.FileName // now contains the full path to the file that the user has selected
```

don't forget to take the result from the ShowDialog() call to make sure the user didn't cancel out of the save dailog!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Path.getfilename() is exactly the method I need. For your solution of using sfd, it seems not work since there's no action of copying file, doesn't it?

Comment: The SaveFileDialog does not actually do any saving, it's just a dialog. It shows the classic dialog that you get in most windows apps when you click "Save" or "Save As".
Ie, it not only lets you choose a folder, but you also get to choose the file name as well.

After the user selects the new file location and name, you are supposed to call the copy function yourself.  File.Copy(remote_address, sfd.FileName);

Comment: OK I guess so. But one more question: The second argument of File.Copy() shall be the local address, namely the folder path + filename. With folderbrowsedialog.SelectedPath I can at least know the path to the folder. But with sfd how could I know the path of the folder I select?

Comment: after the dialog is closed sfd.FileName actually contains the full path (path + file name, ie "c:\test\myFile.txt")


If you preload the .FileName property with "myFile.txt" then when you call ShowDialog it will be in the default folder and be preloaded with "myFile.txt" in the filename field.

You can also set FileName to the full path before opening the dialog. eg  sfd.FileName = "c:\Program Files\MyApp\Saves\save.txt" and it will open the dialog at that location with save.txt as the file name, allowing user to either just acccept as is or modify the location and / or file name.